# What would be a natural way to express the idea of "describe while speaking/describe in speech rather than in writing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What would be a natural way to express the idea of "describe while speaking/describe in speech rather than in writing"? For example:

> Speak and describe these images shown on this page

> Say a description about these images shown on this page

> Talk about these images shown on this page by way of describing

The problem with using verbs like "speak", "say" or "talk" is that they're not specific enough. Moreover, the verb "speak" is mostly intransitive and not very flexible. What I want is to express the command of "describing", only orally.

Comment: You mean deliver a prepared speech, or speak in an extemporised fashion?

Comment: @StuartF No, just speak in a descriptive way. Like in the examples I showed, describe the images, but instead of writing your description, you say it.

Comment: Take their writing/typing instruments away and then ask them the questions. They'll have to speak.

Answer (score 1):

A useful phrase is to **talk on** rather than *talk about*. Consider the second definition below. To talk *on* a subject is to discuss it, to lecture about it.

> [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+on)
>
> 1. To speak continuously and at length.
>
> - Mary talked on for nearly two hours about her trip to Japan.
> - The salesperson on the other end of the phone kept talking on and on, so I eventually just hung up on them.
>
> 2. To discuss or speak about something.
>
> - The panel talked on the various challenges facing the environment today.
> - They brought a police sergeant into the school to talk on the dangers of drug addiction.

Hence, “We are listening to a talk on these images.”